# maintain server socket open

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to keep my socket server open even if an error or exception is thrown

Here is my server

edit:

```
public void serveur()
{
     int maxConnectionAllowed=2;
     int port=5000;

    try{

        serveur = new ServerSocket(port);
        serveur.setReuseAddress(true);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");

        while (true) {
            synchronized (connectedCount) {
                while (connectedCount.get() >= maxConnectionAllowed) {
                    try {
                        connectedCount.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            Socket socket = serveur.accept();   
            factory.processRequest(socket,connectedCount);
        }           
    }



    catch(SocketException sException){
        System.err.println("Error when a socket connects");

    }   
    catch(IOException ioException){
        System.err.println("Error when reading output/input datas");

    }   
      }
public void run() {
    serveur();
}
```

For exemple, the maxConnection simultaneous allowed is 2 , but i connect with a third , an exception is thrown `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` and my serversocket is closed 
I want the server keep running until a place becomes available.

**Edit:**

factory method

```
public void processRequest(Socket socket,AtomicInteger connectedCount) {
    try
    {

    RequestTreatment requestTreatment= new RequestTreatment(socket,connectedCount);
    Thread threadWorker= new Thread(requestTreatment);
    threadWorker.start();
    }
    finally
    {
        compteurConnexion.incrementAndGet();
        synchronized (connectedCount) {
            connectedCount.notify();
        }
    }

}

}
```

Request treatment class

```
public RequestTreatment(Socket socket) {
    super();
    this.socket=socket;

}
@Override
public void run() {
            try
            {
            requestTreatment();
            }
             finally
             {
                try {
                socket.getInputStream().close();
                socket.getOutputStream().close();
                socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 }

            }
          }



public void treatment() {
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();

            // do stuff 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             } 
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: @David Kroukamp thank you for your reply . Yeah , iknow , a simple while(true) resolve the problem , but in my specification i need to limit the connection to 2 clients simultaneous(and i can't use the serversocket constructor , it's a restriction)

Comment: "an exception is thrown "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" and my serversocket is closed". No it isn't. The only way your server socket gets closed is if you close it. That newSocket() method call in the exception handler looks extremely bogus. You don't say *why* you only want to allow two simultaneous connections but if you code it right it doesn't matter how many there are. I'm not convinced there is a real question here.

Comment: LATER: I've taken the trouble to execute your code, which is non-trivial as it doesn't compile as posted, and I cannot reproduce either a `ConnectException` or an unwanted `ServerSocket` closure. I can reproduce other failures, as noted in my answer, but you don't appear to be asking about those. Not a real question.

Comment: Where is the `serveur` variable defined?  Is it local to the method or the main-thread class?

Comment: @EJP first of all , thank you for taking your time to help me .I appreciate your help.  By the way , i am not lying like you are supposing.At the begining , i start my server , then i wait for 2 connection max . if a third connection arrive , the exception"ConnectException" is thrown and the server close(i see it on ecplise and on task manager). Now thanks to your help with Gray i can handle this problem even if i have some trouble with connection pool management with threads

Comment: @Gray it s a main thread class variable

Comment: Nobody has accused you of lying, and you don't know what I am 'supposing' beyond what I have stated here. Don't make statements like that. They only cause offense.

Comment: @EJP Yeah sorry, i was confuse when you say "Not a real question ". I meant no harm ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have your server accept all the connections it can and store them in some sort of list or map (preferably thread safe versions) and have mechanism to process 2 connections at a time by a thread pool of 2. As one process ends you can grab the oldest socket connection from the list and process it.

Edit:

I see that you don't want to allow the third connection so I would change the code to:

```
While(true){
    Socket socket = serveur.accept();
    if(nbClient++< maxConnectionAllowed) factory.processRequest(socket);
    //Else just close the connection and start the loop again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
finally{
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is here. You are starting a new thread to deal with the socket, then you are falling through to this finally block which closes the socket, while the thread is still running. So the thread encounters a 'socket closed' exception. Note that this is *not* the `ServerSocket,` but the accepted `Socket` for the client. This code should be in the finally block of the thread code, not here.

You have another problem here:

```
public RequestTreatment(Socket socket)
{
    super();
    this.socket=socket;
    threadWorker= new Thread(this);
    threadWorker.start();
}
```

This code leaks 'this' before it is fully constructed. You shouldn't start the thread here, you should start it where you do `new RequestTreatment()`.

Comment: The `finally` block looks to be in the `Thread` code to me @EJP.  It's in the `treatment()` method that is called from the `run()` method.  The "do stuff" is in the try block of that finally.

Comment: @EJP thank you for your help but i don t understand when you say "This code leaks 'this' before it is fully constructed" . It means i receive an empty socket ? i will update my code with your changes + gray but i can' t put all because i have confidential part(ie : request treatment protocol). Thank you again

Comment: @user902509 It is always wrong for a constructor to pass 'this' as an argument to another class  (except the parent class). The object being constructed isn't complete yet, so passing it around cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: @EJP Understand ! Because i always pass this in the constructor for for copy the reference in a variable. It ' s a bad practice so.